# Kotlin Android Room handle empty list of objects in Moshi TypeConverter

Tags: android, json, kotlin, type-conversion, moshi

I inherited an Android project where I had to rebase the `rxJava` code to a more pure Kotlin centric code base with a MVVM design pattern.  Given my inexperience, along with lots of head scratching and reading, I finally finished the code conversion.  Sigh! 
But, although testing has gone quite smooth, the new `@TypeConverters` seems more strict and will not allow `empty` lists of expected objects to store in the Room database.
  When the data loads from the server and the item `soil_types` is empty e.g. `soil_types=[]`, I get the error: `Expected receiver of type models.SoilType, but got java.util.ArrayList`. 
Here is the converter:

```
@TypeConverter
fun fromJson(json: String?): List<SoilType>? {
    if(json == null) return null
    return convertJsonToListObject(json)
}

@TypeConverter
fun toJson(objectData: List<SoilType>?): String? {
    if (objectData == null) return null
    return convertListObjectToJson(objectData)
}
//...
inline fun <reified T> convertJsonToListObject(json: String): List<T> =
    moshi.adapter<List<T>>(T::class.java).fromJson(json).orEmpty()

inline fun <reified T> convertListObjectToJson(objectData: List<T>): String =
    moshi.adapter<List<T>>(T::class.java).toJson(objectData)
```

Here is the Room model to be populated:

```
@Entity(tableName = "soil")
data class Soil(
        @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
        val user_id: Long,
        val name: String,
        val soil_types: List<SoilType>,
        val updated_at: String,
        val created_at: String
)
```

I know this is not a good design of a data table column and the relationships that could be built.
My question is how can I allow the converter to accept the `empty ArrayList`, so I can save the `emptyList` as `String resembling '{}'`? Or, I do not want to do this, should I allow for `null`?

Edit:
I tried changing the converter to the following:

```
@TypeConverter
fun fromJson(json: String?): List<SoilType> {
    if(json == null || json == "{}") return emptyList()
    return convertJsonToListObject(json)
}

@TypeConverter
fun toJson(objectData: List<SoilType>?): String {
    if (objectData.isNullOrEmpty()) return "{}"
    return convertListObjectToJson(objectData)
}
```

But the error remains.
Edit 2:
It seems what I am experiencing is built into the [Moshi json library](https://github.com/square/moshi#fails-gracefully) . Upon [further reading](https://proandroiddev.com/getting-started-using-moshi-for-json-parsing-with-kotlin-5a460bf3935a) in section `Moshi handling of null and absent JSON fields`; it seems default values must be declared for data class fields to get expected results:

> If the JSON response changes and sets a null field in the JSON then the adapter will fail respecting the non null reference of a val property in the data class and throw a clear exception.

In this case a `List` of objects that is empty.

Comment: So you've managed to find a solution? If so, I recommend posting an answer:)

Comment: @user3738870 No solution yet.  I found a reference to what may cause the problem, but all my tests has been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: I've tried this and it's working for me when I change `T::class.java` when creating the adapter to `Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, T::class.java)`. Can you try the same?

Comment: @user3738870 It worked!  Thank you very much.  Tried alot of different solutions, but yours worked first time.   If you make your comment the answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually not in Room but in Moshi. Based on its [documentation](https://github.com/square/moshi), you have to do the following in order to parse JSON lists:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> convertJsonToListObject(json: String): List<T> =
    moshi.adapter<List<T>>(Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, T::class.java)).fromJson(json).orEmpty()

inline fun <reified T> convertListObjectToJson(objectData: List<T>): String =
    moshi.adapter<List<T>>(Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, T::class.java)).toJson(objectData)
```

There is also a Kotlin-specific way of doing this, but in Moshi's latest release (1.13.0), you still need to opt in to this feature:

```kotlin
import com.squareup.moshi.adapter

@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
inline fun <reified T> convertJsonToListObject(json: String): List<T> =
    moshi.adapter<List<T>>().fromJson(json).orEmpty()

@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
inline fun <reified T> convertListObjectToJson(objectData: List<T>): String =
    moshi.adapter<List<T>>().toJson(objectData)
```

Arguably, this only complicates your code so it may be worth waiting before using this Kotlin-specific solution.

Comment: Just something to add, if my questions first edit to the `@TypeConverter` method is not added to the end code; the Moshi adapter will save the empty list as `[]` and not `{}`.  I also edited the heading and tags to fit the answer.

Comment: Yes, `[]` is an empty JSON array, which is what we usually want an empty list to be mapped to.